# "Could not complete snapshot" due to ConcurrentModificationException causes Flink pipeline to fail

Tags: apache-flink

After enabling checkpointing for our Flink pipeline, we regularly get the exception below, which causes the pipeline to fail.
The pipeline reads from Kafka, makes some stateless transformations (map) and then writes to HDFS via StreamingFileSink.

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointException: Could not complete snapshot 1080 for operator foo -> bar -> Sink: Hadoop (1/2). Failure reason: Checkpoint was declined.
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.snapshotState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:431)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$CheckpointingOperation.checkpointStreamOperator(StreamTask.java:1282)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$CheckpointingOperation.executeCheckpointing(StreamTask.java:1216)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.checkpointState(StreamTask.java:872)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.performCheckpoint(StreamTask.java:777)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.triggerCheckpointOnBarrier(StreamTask.java:708)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.CheckpointBarrierHandler.notifyCheckpoint(CheckpointBarrierHandler.java:88)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.CheckpointBarrierAligner.processBarrier(CheckpointBarrierAligner.java:113)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.CheckpointedInputGate.pollNext(CheckpointedInputGate.java:155)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskNetworkInput.pollNextNullable(StreamTaskNetworkInput.java:102)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskNetworkInput.pollNextNullable(StreamTaskNetworkInput.java:47)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:135)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:279)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.run(StreamTask.java:301)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:406)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:705)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:530)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1445)
        at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1479)
        at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1477)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.MapSerializer.copy(MapSerializer.java:105)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.MapSerializer.copy(MapSerializer.java:43)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.PojoSerializer.copy(PojoSerializer.java:239)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.streamrecord.StreamElementSerializer.copy(StreamElementSerializer.java:105)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.streamrecord.StreamElementSerializer.copy(StreamElementSerializer.java:46)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.ArrayListSerializer.copy(ArrayListSerializer.java:73)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.PartitionableListState.<init>(PartitionableListState.java:68)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.PartitionableListState.deepCopy(PartitionableListState.java:80)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackendSnapshotStrategy.snapshot(DefaultOperatorStateBackendSnapshotStrategy.java:88)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackend.snapshot(DefaultOperatorStateBackend.java:261)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.snapshotState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:406)
        ... 17 more
```

Currently, there is just a single node, and checkpointing is configured to use the local filesystem:

```
state.backend: filesystem
state.checkpoints.dir: file://opt/flink/checkpoints
```

I am completely unsure how to deal with this error.

This is Flink 1.9.1.

Comment: From your description, I don't see how that could go so wrong. However, Flink 1.9 is also quite battletested for there being such a fundamental bug. Could you please provide your code? Did you use any advanced configuration like `object reuse`?

Comment: @ArvidHeise: If you think this can be investigated, I can try to carve out a minimal example (maybe dropping most intermediate pipeline steps...)

Comment: Having a minimal example is always the easiest way to find the root cause and usually helps the community most. However, I could also take a look at the complete code if you have the possibility. You could also start by briefly explaining your pipeline. It feels as if it's more complex than I initially thought (source is not chained to sink, right?). So it has to be more than a few transformation.

Comment: Trying to extract minimal example, but this might take a while...
The real pipeline has just maps and filters, but one of the maps uses async io, so they are not chained.

Comment: Yes almost thought so. Is it in keyed context? I'm trying to figure out where the map state is coming from. Btw do you modify any record after emitting? How is you async IO working? Most likely we find the root cause there.